# Allow only DNS traffic via Wireguard, block full VPN internet traffic

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, iptables, wireguard

I have VPS and want to share with my family Wireguard and AdguardHome only. I want to pass DNS traffic only and block internal (docker bridge lan) LAN and internet other traffic thru VPN.

Wireguard is on docker with local IP 10.0.0.5
AdguardHome 10.0.0.6
Unbound DNS 10.0.0.7

docker custom bridge network contains Wireguard, Adguard and Unbound containers.

How to do it (maybe with iptables)?
Goal is to pass DNS traffic only.

I know, Wireguard client should be configured like this "AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32" to allow only DNS, but it can be easily changed to "0.0.0.0/0" by the user, so all traffic will pass thru VPN. I want to block that traffic, if someone would try to pass all traffic, the traffic should be blocked (maybe by iptables).

Any solutions? Thanks for help.

Comment: From your question, it is not clear what your network configuration is. In some cases, you can set up a route to the VPN for your DNS servers (example 8.8.8.8). However, if you are concerned that they can change WireGuard, then they can also change everything else. Edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: In other words, I want to block full VPN traffic, in case someone would change AllowedIPs to "0.0.0.0/0". Wireguard should work properly and pass the traffic only when DNS traffic as allowed e.g. AllowedIPs=DNSIP